# I/O Prioritization of Windows OS

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

I was studying Jeffrey Richter Book (Windows via C/C++). In one section, he is talking about I/O prioritization. I know what is prioritization and what are priority class, priority level, and also a base priority now.

I know, I can change the priority of processes and threads with SetPriorityClass and SetThreadPriority but I can't get understand how I/O priority work in Windows 10 or how priority can help us to fine-tune an app which works with storage based devices that has slow performance.

For example, when I have a thread that works with a storage device, what will happen when I set its priority THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN? Is that possible to explain it simply? I read this paper completely ([link](https://clightning.medium.com/i-o-prioritization-in-windows-os-6a0637874a52)) too, but I can't understand the prioritization of I/O.

Comment: Note that, if a storage device is inherently slow, there is nothing much you can do about it.

Comment: @MartinJames is it possible to explain the whole mechanism from scratch? I wanted to know what will happen when I change the priority of a thread to background mode and how the scheduler or device worked with such threads.

Comment: not really.  The I/O subsystems are complex and, at the lower levels, device-specific:(

Comment: The key is I/O _request_ prioritization. If two processes queue an I/O request for the same device, which will be executed first? This is different from the _thread_ priority, which requests CPU usage. A backup-through-network should have a lower I/O priority than your video streaming from the network, so it will have a low I/O priority and the video a high priority. Does this make it clear?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie So when a thread has low priority, it can not make an I/O request when a thread with high priority wanted to make an I/O request to the same device like file system. right?

Comment: No, when a thread has a low _I/O_ priority. It is not about the thread's priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in that paper, it's up to the I/O device driver to handle priority based on the thread priority, and at the time of that paper, there are only two levels, normal and background, which a device driver may ignore.

A device driver could implement the two levels of priority with two I/O request queues, one for normal priority, the other for background priority. The driver could also include logic to prevent the normal queue from completely locking out the background queue by occasionally handling a request from the background queue based on time or request count, even though the normal queue is not empty.

The paper is an old paper, referring to Vista. By now with Windows 10, there may be more than two levels of I/O priority.

Comment: So device drivers will respond to the I/O requests of threads based on their priority right?

Comment: @Cayoot - If there is no current I/O for a device, it will be initiated due to the current I/O request. If the device is busy, the I/O request will be queued, and if implemented by the driver, queued based on priority. In my answer, I used the example of separate I/O requests queues based on priority.

Comment: So I/O requests will be queued based on their priorities and device respond to them separately?

Comment: @Cayoot - If an I/O device only supports one command at a time, then the device is sent one command at a time, and responds at the completion of each command. If an I/O device supports queued commands, such as a hard drive with "native command queuing", the order in which commands are performed may be different than the order those commands were issued, which would interfere with prioritizing I/O. Take a look at [wiki native command queuing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing) . Prioritized command queuing would solve this issue.